# How to pass properties to a method in another namespace

Tags: c#, properties, namespaces

I have defined some settings and plan on defining many more in my VS 2008 C# WPF project.  I am aware that settings can be specified in the project through the settings designer at design time.  I am also aware that the settings can be retrieved and set during run time.  What I would like to do though is be able to access the settings from other assemblies and projects.

I don't understand how this can be done without writing a new class.  Since the settings class is defined in my root namespace, I can't access the settings directly from other assemblies without creating a circular reference (which is what happens if you try to add a reference to a project that is already referencing that project).  Is there a way to pass the properties without having to create a duplicate class with the exact same property definitions?

Comment: In all likelihood, the proper and best way is going to be to create a class containing the property definitions.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: I don't understand your question. Namspaces don't have anything to do with accessibility because you can add `using` statements to import namespaces, or just provide a fully-qualified namespace `global::Some.Namespace.Path.MySettingsClass.SomeSettingsProperty`.

Comment: by any chance don't you mean assembly instead of namespace?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - thank you.  You are probably right.  I don't see any other way around it.

Comment: @Dai - I tried your suggestion of using the global statement, but it won't work without specifying a reference.  Intellisense did not show any other assemblies or namespaces and when I tried to specify one, it generated an error - the type or namespace name could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @caerolus - thank you for the clarification.  I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Is the assembly you try to read form referenced from your project? Or is it an arbitrary assembly that is in some place and you just want to read it without actually using it from your code?

Comment: @Caerolus - I have assembly A that is the main WPF project where the settings.settings file is defined.  It already references assembly B, which is one of the lower level assemblies.  The B assembly is where I would like to access the settings.  It won't let me do this because it would create a circular dependency if I were to try and use A as a reference from B.  It would have been nice if Microsoft had designed the property settings with the bulk of the functionality in a lower level class that could be easily included in any assembly - maybe some sort of dictionary.

Comment: ah, circular dependencies...did you try the code I posted? Another option is to create a 3rd project just for settings, and use it from A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you're trying to read properties from an assembly that you did not reference in your project. In that case, [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the answer.

Read the info from that assembly, wherever the `dll` is. Load the `Settings` class, get the `Default` settings, and access the parameter you want.

As an example, I have a dll called `se2.dll`, with a parameter that I'd normally access as:

```
string parameterValue = se2.Settings2.Default.MyParameter;
```

Now, from a different project, I have to use reflection like this:

```
// load assembly
 System.Reflection.Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"M:\Programming\se2\se2\bin\Debug\se2.exe");
// load Settings2 class and default object
Type settingsType = ass.GetType("se2.Settings2");
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo defaultProperty = settingsType.GetProperty("Default");
object defaultObject = defaultProperty.GetValue(settingsType, null);
// invoke the MyParameter property from the default settings
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo parameterProperty = settingsType.GetProperty("MyParameter");
string parameterValue = (string)parameterProperty.GetValue(defaultObject, null);
```

Comment: I had not considered using reflection.  This is a good idea worth exploring.  My app is a real time one and concerned with performance though, so I'm not sure if the code would have to use late binding.  I know from what I have read in the past that you can sometimes choose whether it uses early or late binding.  I have also been reading that properties are slow and Jeffery Richter is not very fond of them - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694711/why-should-i-avoid-using-properties-in-c?rq=1/

Comment: That properties are (slightly) slower than fields doesn't apply here anyway, because the settings files generate properties :-)

Comment: btw, concerning efficiency: wouldn't you read the settings just once? probably at the app start? maybe settings auto-generated code is not the best here.

Comment: Well, once the project is set up to use a settings file, it reads them in automatically when the program is launched.  So, when code like this is written -   string Addr = Properties.Settings.Default.LobbyAddress;  It picks up the value without me having to write any code to load them.  So, I guess I will write a separate class to store them.  Thanks for your help.