# Point of separate get-set without any additional operations or different accessibility levels?

Tags: c#

Looking through some code for a built-in Sharepoint webpart, I stumbled upon the following piece of code. What's the practical use of a separate get/set that only modify a different variable when both of them have the same accessibility level? Neither the getter nor the setter execute any additional code either.

```
private int m_CompatibilityLevel = 14;
private int CompatibilityLevel
{
    get
    {
        return this.m_CompatibilityLevel;
    }
    set
    {
        this.m_CompatibilityLevel = value;
    }
}
```

Wouldn't it be easier/more reasonable to use a single variable and give it a value wherever code execution begins? Or is this considered better design?

Comment: Maybe it **was a public/protected** property. **Or** maybe it has been added **just for debugging** (you can set a breakpoint in getter/setter). For what we can see from that code is just pretty useless. About design: IMO a property is often a _leak_ in OOP because it exposes object internal state (unless your class is a mere entity) and I don't see any advantage to also adopt them for private fields...

Comment: I'd guess that code was written before the C# compiler supported auto properties.

Comment: As far as I can see, it doesn't offer any additional insight, but the rest of the code can be viewed [on Gist over here](https://gist.github.com/Etheryte/8cca6b22b145d8c976ea).

Comment: @JoeWhite When was it introduced? The code is from Sharepoint 2013, which was first released at the end of 2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I avoid using Properties in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694711/why-should-i-avoid-using-properties-in-c)

Comment: @Nit, auto properties were introduced in C# 3.0 (released along with .NET 3.5 in November 2007). But just because this code sample was released with Sharepoint 2013 doesn't mean it was originally written for Sharepoint 2013. It could have been originally written long ago and never updated.

Comment: @JoeWhite Good point, there was a similar (but not identical) webpart in Sharepoint 2007, but I haven't checked how much they differ in code, a lot of the code might be just ported over.